# How can I use gtkmm with MinGW (g++) without MSYS?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, gtkmm, msys

How can I use gtkmm with MinGW (g++) without MSYS?

Here is the story of my problem:

I installed MinGW offline with all required packages (full install). I installed Apache Server and I copied all .tar.gz files and I created a website called sourceforge.org [localhost] and I installed automatically MinGW on Windows XP. After that, I set the PATH variables.

I installed gtkmm for MinGW (g++). I tried to compile a simple window with gtkmm + MinGW, but it does not work.

I use this command line:

```
g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

After this, I installed MSYS and I can compile simple.cc with MSYS, using this command line:

```
g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

My problem:
I want to compile `simple.cc` without MSYS. I want compile my `simple.cc` with cmd.exe - Is this possible? If, yes. How?

---

base.cc source code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
Gtk::Window window;
Gtk::Main::run(window);
return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs
```

Result:

```
-mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4-IC:/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Command line:

```
g++ base.cc -o base `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

Result:

```
g++: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: gtkmm-2.4: No such file or directory
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fcflags"
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-flibs`"
```

Command line:

```
g++ base.cc -o base -D_REENTRANT -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4-IC:/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Result:
Many errors looks like:

```
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:269: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `get_icon' with no type
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: `Gio' has not been dec
lared
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: `Icon' was not declare
d in this scope
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `property_gicon' with no type
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: `Gio' has not been dec
lared
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: `Icon' was not declare
d in this scope
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `property_gicon' with no type
```

Command line:

```
g++ base.cc -o base -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4-IC:/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Result:
Many errors looks like:

```
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:269: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `get_icon' with no type
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: `Gio' has not been dec
lared
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: `Icon' was not declare
d in this scope
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:589: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `property_gicon' with no type
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: `Gio' has not been dec
lared
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: `Icon' was not declare
d in this scope
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: template argument 1 is
 invalid
C:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/statusicon.h:599: error: ISO C++ forbids declar
ation of `property_gicon' with no type
```

By the way, I'm also using ``, looks like:

```
g++ base.cc -o base `-mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4-IC:/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`
```

if I use MSYS I can compile base.cc, but I need to compile it without MSYS.
Another information (perhaps necessary) about PATH (maybe here is the wrong):

Path 1:

Variable name: path
Variable value: C:\MinGW\bin

Path 2:

Variable name: PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Variable value: C:\gtkmm\lib\pkgconfig
What can I do?
Please help me to solve my problem.
I apologize for my English level (in case you did not properly understand my message).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your command line, I'm guessing `pkg-config` is going to output a set of libraries and compile flags.  If you can determine what the output will be for your machine, you can simply substitute that output in place of the command.

I've done something similar when working with SDL.  It provides an `sdl-config` script that has a predictable output on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. First of all Windows command prompt doesn't work with back tics.

Therefore the following command or similar is not going to work.

```
g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

The solution is to run `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs` on the command line and copy paste the output in the end of `g++ base.cc -o base`.

The following code you posted is closest to correct. For my eyes this command should work.

```
g++ base.cc -o base -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/giomm-2.4-IC:/gtkmm/lib/giomm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pangomm-1.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/atkmm-1.6 -IC:/gtkmm/include/gdkmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gdkmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glibmm-2.4 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/sigc++-2.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairomm-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtkmm/include/cairo -IC:/gtkmm/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtkmm/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/libpng14 -IC:/gtkmm/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtkmm/include/atk-1.0  -LC:/gtkmm/lib -lgtkmm-2.4 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-2.4 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0-lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

The environment variable paths should be correct as long as you have the utilities installed on those directory paths.

Comment: If you are familiar with Eclipse or allow using IDE as an answer now Eclipse CDT supports pkg-config via plug-in.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt/edit
Any feedback is welcome!